# Force Applied but No Distance Travelled

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, energy, work

Suppose I push on a wall with a constant force of 5 N for 10 s. The wall won't move and hence no work will be done on the wall. However, pushing requires energy. How can I find out how much energy I need to produce a constant force of 5 N for 10 s?

After seeing force and time together, I immediately thought of impulse. But I'm not sure if that helps here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pushing requires energy

In fact, pushing does not require energy. You can lean a ladder against a wall and without consuming energy it will tirelessly push against the wall until the wall crumbles or the ladder is moved away.

If a human being wants to push on the wall with their arm then they will find that human arms are inefficient machines and in this situation have an efficiency of 0% meaning that consumed energy goes entirely into heat without producing any external work. This is not because pushing requires energy but because humans are inefficient machines for such tasks.

Comment: So in general, the amount of energy required depends on the machine itself?

Comment: No, the amount of energy required is not dependent on the machine. But the amount of energy consumed is dependent on the machine itself. The ratio between the amount of energy required and the amount of energy consumed is called the efficiency of the machine.